# \documentclass{article}: do not show date

Tags: article

My Latex code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
Document's text.
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

How can I not show the document's date?

Comment: Add `\date{}` before `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert

```
\vspace{-8ex}
\date{}
```

before `\begin{document}`. You can adjust the vertical space as per your requirement.

Comment: There's an extra "}" after `\vspace` – moreover, the `\vspace` command has no effect before `\begin{document}` – and lastly `\date{}` will automatically eliminate the space reserved for the date, so no need for negative space